# Сохраняется ли тире при перестановке слов? Землю ― крестьянам, крестьянам ― землю?

Tags: пунктуация

Сохраняется ли тире при перестановке слов? Пример: Землю ― крестьянам, крестьянам ― землю? По какому правилу ставится здесь тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном примере тире сохраняется, поскольку в обоих случаях опущен глагол: "*(нужно) отдать*". Тире здесь замещает пропущенное.